# Having trouble creating generic Dart constructor for Json conversion

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, inheritance, networking

To all Dart gurus: I'm trying to implement a generic networking layer in Dart that converts REST service response to a specified model class:

```
// The idea is to make a network call and get a deserialized model as a response:

final token =
        await _authNetworkService.execute<AccessTokenResponse>(request);
```

Here is the implementation:

```
// Model interface
abstract class JsonConvertible {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
  JsonConvertible.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}

// Model
class AccessTokenResponse extends JsonConvertible {
  String? accessToken;

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {};
  }

  @override
  AccessTokenResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : super.fromJson(json) {
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
  }
}

// Network response class
class NetworkResponse<Model> {
  Model data;
  
  NetworkResponse.ok(this.data);
}

// Class to create a valid network service request
class NetworkRequest {
}

// Class that performs all network calls
class NetworkService {
  Future<NetworkResponse<M>> execute<M extends JsonConvertible>(NetworkRequest request) async {
    // For simplicity replaced all DIO calls with static data:
    final response = {'data': {'access_token': 'XXX'}};

    return NetworkResponse.ok(M.fromJson(response['data'])); //<- Fails here with error: Method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'...
  }
}
```

DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=9a29a7e49a084e69fd1d8078d5f2b977

How can I achieve expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you can solve this is by passing the **fromJson** constructor as an argument to the **execute** function but this will add another step for every time **execute** is called

```
// Class that performs all network calls
class NetworkService {
  Future<NetworkResponse<M>> execute<M extends JsonConvertible>(NetworkRequest request,M Function(Map<String, dynamic>) parser ) async {
    // For simplicity replaced all DIO calls with static data:
    final response = {'data': {'access_token': 'XXX'}};

    return NetworkResponse.ok( parser(response['data']!)); //<- Fails here with error: Method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'...
  }
}
```

and this is how you would call the **execute** function

```
 final token =
        await _authNetworkService.execute<AccessTokenResponse>(request,AccessTokenResponse.fromJson);
```